# how to add marker over the polyline but after every 20 Km?

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, marker, google-polyline

I am using the Google Maps in iOS.I have drawn a polyline between source and destination.Now i want to add markers in between the route but after every 20 Kms. Can anyone plz help me out that how to find the point over the polyline after every 20 Kms and add marker over it ?

Comment: ["km marker" example (markers every 2km)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html), [markers at 2 specific distances along a route (9.5km and 64.8km)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

Comment: [example with marker every mile on route from the directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_kmMarkersFromDirections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have an array of all of the points. You can iterate over this array and calculate (and accumulate) the distance between each pair of points. Each time you get to 20km, add the marker at the current location and reset the accumulation count.

Apples `CLLocation` class offers the `distanceFromLocation:` method which may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But According to Apple documentation, "distanceFromLocation:" method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations. But i want to find the distance driving by road.

Comment: How far apart are each of your points? If you're plotting the route then it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: But points are coming dynamically depending on route.If we calculate the distance from one point to another, then its coming somewhat different from the actual ones. Just for example,Suppose i have given the points of source and destination only, then the distance coming out is different from the actual one.

Comment: Yes, I have array of points. But i just gave an example that distance coming by using this method is not giving the actual results i.e the actual distance. Is there any other way @Wain ?

Comment: Each point you have should basically be a turn in the road. So the total distance is the sum of all of the straight lines between the points. No? Did you try to calculate and get a mismatch? Are you sure the units are comparable?